# working with bits

Tags: c++

**program**:

```
typedef bitset<8> bits;
char original = 0xF0F0F0F0;
char Mask = 0xFFFF0000;
char newBits = 0x0000AAAA;

/*& operation with "0bit set 0" & "1bit give no change to original byte" */
cout<<"Original o: "<<bits(original)<<endl;
cout<<"NewBits: "<<bits(newBits)<<endl;
cout<<"Mask m: "<<bits(Mask)<<endl;
cout<<"o & m with Mask: "<<bits(original & Mask)<<endl;/*0 set original bit as 0 */
```

**Result**:

> Original o: 11110000
>   
> NewBits: 10101010
>   
> Mask m: 00000000
>   
> o & m with Mask: 00000000
>   
> Result 10101010

I understand the hex & its result.. but....... `o & m` == `0000 0000` so `bits(o & m | newBits)` result should be `0000 0000`, not `1010 1010`...

Where i am missing the  concept...

Can anyone  help me please...

Expecting a good response

Thanks

Comment: `char original = 0xF0F0F0F0;`? Really? How about giving real code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`o & m = 0000 0000` and `newBits = 1010 1010`. So if you OR them (bitwise) you will get the result as `1010 1010` as `0|0=0, 0|1=1, 1|0=1, 1|1=1`.

```
0000 0000 OR WITH
1010 1010
-----------------
1010 1010
-----------------
```

Comment: @Miss: You can accept the answer using the tick on the left. This closes the question as answered and gives additional reward to the answerer.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: 1111 0000, here LSB is 0 and MSB is 1.. am i right?